# kdenlive - pop-up dialogues don't draw correctly - probably missing library

Tags: kdenlive

I'm trying to use kdenlive, but when the Open/Save or other pop-up dialogues happen, they don't draw correctly ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM3BE.png ). They draw what was behind them, but never actually end up drawing.

Now, I tried to use kdenlive from the main repos, then added the kdenlive PPA, installed that version, but no improvement. So I'm on kdenlive 18.04.1, to be explicit, currently. I then tried installing the kubuntu-desktop meta package, as a heavy-handed way to try and get the library that I may be missing, but no fix there.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

BTW I'm on 18.04, XFCE4 + Compiz

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem: the Open/Save menus were all somehow behind the kdenlive main window if it was maximized.

So the workaround is to move the main window when accessing the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had two versions, I think the old version was being ran by the application menu, but when I ran kdenlive by the CLI, the working version was launched, and the pop-up menus worked!

So I "apt purge kdenlive" and "apt install kdenlive" to reinstall it, and the one from the start menu now works properly too! YAY!

Thanks Ask Reddit! ;D